# Consequences of changing a value (struct) type to a reference (class) type

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

Consider a `struct` type defined as follows:

```
public struct Device
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Data {get; set;}

    public void UploadData(DataSource source)
    {
        source.data += Data;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to change the `Device` to a `class` type and use it to describe different types of devices:

```
public class Device
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Data {get; set;}

    public virtual void UploadData(DataSource source)
    {
        source.data += Data;
    }
}
```

I'm aware that one should be cautious in making this step because the parameters are passed by reference in the second case. But somehow I can't figure out a use case where this change will have negative consequences for uploading data to the data source.

Comment: "the parameters are passed by reference in the second case" - no they're not. The reference is passed by value. It's really important to understand the difference. See https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: `var a = new Device() { Name = "a"};  var b=  a; b.Name = "b";` Compare and contrast (i.e. run the code, look at `b` and `a` when class, then as struct).

Comment: @JonSkeet, oh.. now I see the difference. Great article btw! Was a pleasure to read.

Comment: @mjwills, makes sense:) if you like, you can post this comment as an answer and i"ll accept it.